# Getting the doorbell signal to my raspberry pi

Tags: pi-1

This is the first time I'm doing such a project. 
I haven't started yet. Right now I have the raspberry pi in pic 1 (the original I think). If i press the button (pic 2/3) A signal goes towards the box (pic 4/5) and a sound is played. Is it possible to somehow connect the raspberry pi with the box, such that I can see when the button has been pressed and potentially do something with it if a signal arrived. How would be the best way to do this?

[image: raspberry pi]

[image: Doorbell]
[image: Doorbell]

[image: Box]
[image: Box]

Comment: Hello - welcome to Raspberry Pi SE. You've chosen a great project to start with, and it's been done many times. This [Google search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=raspberry+pi+doorbell+project) provides many articles that will help you get started. Please also read [how to ask a good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck, and let us know if you're struggling with something specific.

Comment: Someone might stand a chance of helping you work out how to connect to the receiver if you could provide a clear, in-focus high-res picture of the PCB - both sides if possible.

Comment: So it looks like there are some wires connecting the box to a speaker. You could cut those wires and use them to alert your pi that the doorbell has been pressed. Let me know if you want more details, but for now you should get started by learning the basics of python3, then learning gpiozero or rpi.gpio, then learning how to connect a button to your pi and get the input. From there, you can learn how to **_SAFELY_** connect the doorbell reciever to your pi.

Comment: looks like a wireless doorbell ... do you have **any** specifications, model number (TAN2221 doesn't come up with anything useful in google), brand, etc

Answer (score 1):

> somehow connect the raspberry pi with the box

Let me see.  I guess the box is a wireless door bell receiver.  When you press the button of a box at the other end, the transmitter, a wireless signal is sent out.  The receiver box gets the signal and starts its job, activates a buzzer, or plays music.

The buzzer is usually an NE555 like oscillator with audio/low frequency output connected to a power amplifier with output to a 4 Ohm speaker.

Now you can extract the electrical signal at the output of the oscillator, ie, input of the power amplifier (see below for a very simple example) usually 3V to 9V square/sine wave like like signal, convert it to 3V to 5V level if necessary, and use a Vcc = 3V3 Schmitt trigger logic gate, 74HC14 for example, to get a 3V level digital signal.

Rpi GPIO would now happily read the converted 3V digital signal.

If you don't want to mess around with the scary electronics stuff inside the box, then you can consider the connect by air or sound wave method, using a cheap sound detector.  The sound detector listens to the door bell ring or music and outputs 3V/5V digital signal for the Rpi to read.

[image: sound detector]

[image: simple power amp]